# CSV > Calc - Text to Date

Tags: csv, openoffice-calc

I imported a CSV file into Calc. Unfortunately, formatting a text field as a date field in Calc leaves the leading '.

I wrote the following function, but continue to get *Error 508 - error in bracketing.* I have re-bracketed a bunch of different ways, but I'm not very VBA savvy.

```
=IF('sheet1'!(LEFT(G4, 1) = "'"); ('sheet1'!H4 = (RIGHT(G4, 10))))
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice uses semicolon separators rather than the comma separators required by Excel.  Replace the commas in your LEFT and RIGHT functions with semicolons.

OpenOffice uses a dot separator after a sheet name.  Replace your exclamation marks with dots.

The sheet name has to immediately proceed the cell name.  Move your first sheetname inside the LEFT function so it immediately proceeds G4.

The second argument in an IF function is what you want displayed if the test is true.  There should be no comparator such as = meaning you need to delete "'sheet1'!H4 = ".

Taking all those steps will stop the error message, but it will not solve your problem.

Moving on, your IF statement is a spreadsheet function.
VBA is used to write macros in Microsoft Office products such as Excel.  StarBasic would be the equivalent in Calc.  You are not writing anything in VBA or any other variant of Basic.  Neither language is related to the spreadsheet functions.  You are writing a spreadsheet equation.

More importantly, the leading ' is not considered part of the cell contents and cannot be detected by the LEFT function nor removed by the RIGHT function.  **Your problem is best addressed by re-opening the CSV file and changing the import filter settings so that your dates are correctly imported as dates.**

A second option would be to highlight all the cells with dates and choose the menu command Data->Text To Columns then hit OK.  After using the Text To Columns, you may need to right-click the cells, choose "Format Cells", look on the tab "Numbers" and choose the option "Date" (then press OK).